# Why does my PDO object return object(PDO)[2]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi i am working on a basic databse connection class for mysql using PDO, however when i var dump the return result it tells me i has 2 objects: `object(PDO)[2]`. Should it not be only one ?

**Here is my code so far:**

```
class DBConnection
{
    // Settings (DSN)
    protected $driver, $host, $name, $charset;

    // Credentials
    protected $user, $pass;

    // PDO Connection
    protected $connection;

    public function __construct() {
        require_once( 'database.config.php' );

        // Settings (DSN)
        $this->driver   = DB_DRIVER;
        $this->host     = DB_HOST;
        $this->name     = DB_NAME;
        $this->charset  = DB_CHARSET;

        // Credentials
        $this->user     = DB_USER;
        $this->pass     = DB_PASS;

        // Initialise Connection
        var_dump($this->getConnection());
    }

    private function getConnection() {
        // Check if connection is already established
        if ( $this->connection == NULL ) {
            $dsn = "$this->driver:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->name;charset=$this->charset";
            try {
                $this->connection = new PDO($dsn,$this->user, $this->pass);
                $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch ( PDOException $error ) {
                echo 'Connection failed: ' . $error->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return $this->connection;
    }
}

$new = new DBConnection();
```

**Config file:**

```
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'test');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
```

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($new)`? What does that return?

Comment: @SK.FazleeRabby, `var_dump($new)` return a list if properties and methods of the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private function getConnection() {
    // Check if connection is already established
    if ( $this->connection == NULL ) {
        $dsn = "$this->driver:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->name;charset=$this->charset";
        try {
            $this->connection = new PDO($dsn,$this->user, $this->pass);
            $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            // This line is to remove associate array, then you will get only one object in result set
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        } catch ( PDOException $error ) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $error->getMessage();
        }
    }
    return $this->connection;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding `$this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ` But i stll get the same result. Are you saying that one of the 2 objects a associative array and the other is somthing else?

Comment: @FrederickM.Rogers nah, `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` is to return a table with element indexed by column names. Default (`PDO::FETCH_BOTH`) return the same **AND** elements indexed by column numbers [[here the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)]. But here it's not really your problem.

Comment: @FanieVoid, would the number following the PDO object reflect the number of active connections?

Comment: @FrederickM.Rogers it can be that... Where are you closing your connection ? it's not visible in you code

Comment: @FanieVoid at the moment i am not closing the connection at all, is that something i should be doing ?

Comment: @FrederickM.Rogers in the doc, it is said that the connection is automatically closed at the end of the script, but I would think it's better to just close it when you don't need it anymore... My question was more are you opening two connections in your script

Comment: @FanieVoid not on purpose, but it might be happening by accident as i do instantiate the connection class in other classes.

Comment: @FrederickM.Rogers then you can try to put your var which contains the PDO connection to `null` when you don't need it anymore

Comment: @FanieVoid, no luck has to be something in my other classes.